# Grouping object-group configuration using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, cisco

I have a config from Cisco ASA and I need to write a Python RegEx to capture everything that is in the object-groups and group them for further processing.

For example:

```
object-group network FTP
 description FTP Access
 network-object host BCD1
 network-object host BCD2
object-group network NTP
 description NTP Access
 network-object host ABC1
 network-object host ABC2
 network-object host ABC3
object-group service sample_service tcp
 description Ports 1 2 3
 port-object range 80 81
 port-object eq pop3
 port-object eq imap4
 port-object range 443 444
object-group service 8080 tcp
 description Servers
```

The end result should be something like this:

```
Group 1: object-group network FTP
          description FTP Access
          network-object host BCD1
          network-object host BCD2

Group 2:  object-group network NTP
          description NTP Access
          network-object host ABC1
          network-object host ABC2
etc.
```

As I said I am very bad at this, but I tried to come up with something but the result was horrible

```
(object-group\s[^!]*)object or (object-group[^!]*)
```

Both of them failed.

Comment: It is suffice to mention that your regexps are not reliable since `[^!]*` matches any character(s) that are not `!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex written with the unroll-the-loop technique in mind:

```
\bobject-group\b\S*(?:\s+(?!object-group\b)\S*)*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG3oG5/3). It is basically the same as `(?s)object-group(?:(?!\bobject-group\b).)*`, or `(?s)object-group.*?(?=\bobject-group\b|$)`, but is more efficient.

*Explanation:*

- `\bobject-group\b` - literal sequence of characters `object-group` (a whole word due to `\b` word boundaries)
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+(?!object-group\b)\S*)*` - zero or more sequences of...

  - `\s+(?!object-group\b)` - 1 or more whitespace symbols that are not followed with `object-group` whole word
  - `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace symbols.

[Python code](https://ideone.com/Ko7V6B):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\bobject-group\b\S*(?:\s+(?!object-group\b)\S*)*')
test_str = "object-group network FTP\n description FTP Access\n network-object host BCD1\n network-object host BCD2\nobject-group network NTP\n description NTP Access\n network-object host ABC1\n network-object host ABC2\n network-object host ABC3\nobject-group service sample_service tcp\n description Ports 1 2 3\n port-object range 80 81\n port-object eq pop3\n port-object eq imap4\n port-object range 443 444\nobject-group service 8080 tcp\n description Servers"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Comment: Thank you very much stribizhev! The regex works! One quick question it is not a big deal I already found a work around, but if you can help me will be awesome. After group-objects comes access-list configuration and your regex captures them as well. Is there a way to exclude them from the match. My hole goal is to open the running config and do regex on it without chopping it to pieces.

Comment: I believe all you need is to add that string as an alternative: [`\bobject-group\b\S*(?:\s+(?!(?:access-list|object-group)\b)\S*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/hG3oG5/4).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a complicated, difficult to understand, regex to do this. Simply iterate over the file breaking on lines that begin with `object-group` and build up a dictionary of lists.

You can do it with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) or a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of `list`. I prefer the latter which will give you a dictionary useful for further processing:

```
from collections import defaultdict

object_groups = defaultdict(list)
key = 0
with open('cisco.cfg') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('object-group'):
            key += 1
        object_groups[key].append(line.strip())

from pprint import pprint
pprint(object_groups.items())
```

Assuming your sample input, the output would be:

```
[(1,
  ['object-group network FTP',
   'description FTP Access',
   'network-object host BCD1',
   'network-object host BCD2']),
 (2,
  ['object-group network NTP',
   'description NTP Access',
   'network-object host ABC1',
   'network-object host ABC2',
   'network-object host ABC3']),
 (3,
  ['object-group service sample_service tcp',
   'description Ports 1 2 3',
   'port-object range 80 81',
   'port-object eq pop3',
   'port-object eq imap4',
   'port-object range 443 444']),
 (4, ['object-group service 8080 tcp', 'description Servers'])]
```

Also, you could instead use the object group identifiers as keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

object_groups = defaultdict(list)
key = None
with open('cisco.cfg') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('object-group'):
#            key = line.strip()                      # the whole line
            key = line.strip().partition(' ')[-1]    # just the object group definition
        else:
            object_groups[key].append(line.strip())

from pprint import pprint
pprint(object_groups.items())
```

which will create a similar dictionary but with keys `'network FTP'`, `'network NTP'`, `'service sample_service tcp'` etc.

Comment: Thanks for showing this to me mhawke! This is really awesome. I love this method because I don't have to write regex!

Comment: @gh0st: exactly. regex can be difficult to understand and maintain. This method is easy to understand, and to later modify if, as usual, inevitable. Not sure then why you have accepted a regex answer, but perhaps that is your requirement?

Comment: I wish I could select both answers, and to be honest  I liked your answer more because I can understand the logic behind it, but my question was regarding regex and stribizhev answered it. It would be unfair if I leave his work unnoticed. You went an extra mile an showed me completely different approach and I appreciate that very much!

Comment: @gh0st: That's fair enough.